# matplotlib analog of R's `pairs`

Tags: python, r, matplotlib

R has a useful function `pairs` that provides nice matrix of plots of pairwise connections between variables in a data set. The resulting plot looks similar to the following figure, copied from [this blog post](http://statisticsr.blogspot.com/2009/12/r-pairs-plot.html):

[image: pairs]

Is there any ready to use function based on python's matplolib? I have searched its [gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html), but couldn't find anything that resembles what I need.  Technically, this should be a simple task, but proper handling of all the possible cases, labels, titles, etc is very tedious.

**UPDATE** see below my answer with a quick and dirty approximation.

Comment: Seaborn has this, see: http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[`Pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) has a built in function `scatter_matrix` ([source code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tools/plotting.py#L28)) which is something like this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
axes = pd.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('scatter_matrix.png')
```

[image: scatter_matrix.png]

However it is `pandas` specific (but could be used as a starting point).

There are some more `R` like plots in pandas. Have a look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Comment: Great answer! On recent versions of pandas it's now pd.plotting.scatter_matrix

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty approximation to my needs:

```
def pair(data, labels=None):
    """ Generate something similar to R `pair` """

    nVariables = data.shape[1]
    if labels is None:
        labels = ['var%d'%i for i in range(nVariables)]
    fig = pl.figure()
    for i in range(nVariables):
        for j in range(nVariables):
            nSub = i * nVariables + j + 1
            ax = fig.add_subplot(nVariables, nVariables, nSub)
            if i == j:
                ax.hist(data[:,i])
                ax.set_title(labels[i])
            else:
                ax.plot(data[:,i], data[:,j], '.k')

    return fig
```

The code above is hereby released into the public domain

Comment: To me there is extra value in base module code. This is very clear, I’ll take it as instructive for data manipulation tasks. One question: what object types may ‘data’ be?

Comment: @Merlin it looks like it's designed for Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

The `subplots` function in recent versions of matplotlib (at least 1.4) makes this a little bit easier:

```
def pairs(data, names):
    "Quick&dirty scatterplot matrix"
    d = len(data)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=d, ncols=d, sharex='col', sharey='row')
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(d):
            ax = axes[i,j]
            if i == j:
                ax.text(0.5, 0.5, names[i], transform=ax.transAxes,
                        horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center',
                        fontsize=16)
            else:
                ax.scatter(data[j], data[i], s=10)
```

Comment: If applied on a dataset standard for scikit-learn, `len(data)` will return the number of observations, not the number of variables. `d = data.shape[1]` is the solution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions(after 0.23.3 or maybe in few version earlier too) you can use:

```
In [80]: from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

In [81]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

In [82]: scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6), diagonal='kde')
```

`diagonal` can assume values like `kde`, `hist`.
[image: scatter_matrix]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [seaborn pairplot(...) function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) . It's quite like the pairs(...) function in R.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's not a ready-to-use function like that.

Answer (score 0):

From a post, I get this:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
def reg_coef(x,y,label=None,color=None, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    r,p = pearsonr(x,y)
    if p < 0.01:
        sig_level = '***'
    elif p < 0.05:
        sig_level = '**'
    elif p < 0.05:
        sig_level = '*'
    else:
        sig_level = ''
        
    ax.annotate('r = {:.2f} {}'.format(r, sig_level), xy=(0.5,0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center')
    ax.texts[0].set_size(16)
    ax.set_axis_off()

# Create the plot
g = sns.PairGrid(data=X1, vars=columns, hue=None)
g.map_upper(reg_coef)
g = g.map_lower(sns.regplot, scatter_kws={"edgecolor": "white"})
g = g.map_diag(sns.histplot, kde=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).