# Labels for scatterplot-matrices

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, axis-labels

I have been trying to plot a scatterplot matrix using the great [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941207/is-there-a-function-to-make-scatterplot-matrices-in-matplotlib) given by Joe Kington:

However, I would like to add xlabels and ylabels on the subplots where I have displayed ticks. When you change the positions of the ticks, the associated x/ylabel does not follow.
I have not been able to find an option to change the location of the label; I was hoping to find something like `ax.set_xlabel('XLabel',position='top')` but it does not exist.

This is what I get finally,

[image]
For example I would like X axis4 to be above the ticks.

Comment: Can you show us the _exact_ code you are using to generate that graph?  Not having to guess what you are doing makes it easier to help;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the x-label from bottom to top, or the y-label from left to right, you can (provided the specific suplot is called `ax`) do it by calling:

```
ax.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
```

If you for example want the label "X label 2" to stay where it is but don't overlap the other subplot, you can try to add a

```
fig.tight_layout()
```

just before the `fig.show()`.