# define size of individual subplots side by side

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter, subplot

I am using subplots side by side

```
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
# plot 1
plt.xlabel('MEM SET')
plt.ylabel('Memory Used')
plt.bar(inst_memory['MEMORY_SET_TYPE'], inst_memory['USED_MB'], alpha = 0.5, color = 'r')
# pol 2
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.xlabel('MEM POOL')
plt.ylabel('Memory Used')
plt.bar(set_memory['POOL_TYPE'], set_memory['MEMORY_POOL_USED'], alpha = 0.5, color = 'g')
```

they have identical size - but is it possible to define the width for each subplot, so the right one could be wider as it has more entries and text would not squeeze or would it be possible to replace the bottom x-text by a number and have a legend with 1:means xx   2:means yyy
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I find GridSpec helpful for subplot arrangements, see [this demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/userdemo/demo_gridspec03.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-demo-gridspec03-py) at matplotlib.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import pandas as pd
N=24

inst_memory = pd.DataFrame({'MEMORY_SET_TYPE': np.random.randint(0,3,N),
                   'USED_MB': np.random.randint(0,1000,N)})
set_memory = pd.DataFrame({'MEMORY_POOL_USED': np.random.randint(0,1000,N),
                   'POOL_TYPE': np.random.randint(0,10,N)})

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[1, 2],wspace=0.3)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])

ax1.bar(inst_memory['MEMORY_SET_TYPE'], inst_memory['USED_MB'], alpha = 0.5, color = 'r')
ax2.bar(set_memory['POOL_TYPE'], set_memory['MEMORY_POOL_USED'], alpha = 0.5, color = 'g')
```

You may need to adjust `width_ratios` and `wspace` to get the desired layout.

Also, rotating the text in x-axis might help, some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19273945/11305111).

Comment: yes, thanks - I have used gridspec for sizing and rotate for x-labels... many thanks for all answers..  best regards, Guy