# Using matplotlib set_pickradius correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, highlight, picker

I had a previous question on how to highlight data points in matplotlib using a `pick_event` ([this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171626/pyplot-highlight-point-selected-with-picker)). The solution worked fine until matplotlib  changed the usage of the keyword `picker`. Now I can't get it work anymore. Here is the MWE that worked before:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyPlot(object):

    def makePlot(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure('Test', figsize=(10, 8))
        ax = plt.subplot(111)
        x = range(0, 100, 10)
        y = (5,)*10
        ax.plot(x, y, '-', color='red')
        ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='blue', picker=5)
        self.highlight, = ax.plot([], [], 'o', color='yellow')
        self.cid = plt.connect('pick_event', self.onPick)
        plt.show()

    def onPick(self, event=None):
        this_point = event.artist
        x_value = this_point.get_xdata()
        y_value = this_point.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind
        self.highlight.set_data(x_value[ind][0],y_value[ind][0])
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyPlot()
    app.makePlot()
```

Now I changed this line:

```
        ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='blue', picker=5)
```

to this:

```
        ax.xaxis.set_pickradius(5.)
        ax.yaxis.set_pickradius(5.)
```

according to the documentation, but the highlighting does not work anymore. What else do I have to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some wild random testing I just found the solution.
Instead of

```
ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='blue', picker=5)
```

I must use

```
ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='blue', picker=True)
ax.xaxis.set_pickradius(5.)
ax.yaxis.set_pickradius(5.)
```

Looks like the keyword `picker` only accepts bools or functions, but not floats anymore. And yes, it is actually in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_picker.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_picker), was just looking at the wrong place.