# ERROR: ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only when I try to do a scatter plot using statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm new to Python and the relative question I read didn't make much sense to me. I have the following issue. I want to use Python to do multiple regression and I am trying statsmodels. In this case I want to do a scatter plot.

Sample of my data:

```
ID  order  V1     V2    E1  E2  E3   M
103  1    ECA    TEXT    7   3   5   7
105  1    ECA    TEXT    3   7   4   5
107  1    ECA    TEXT    7   7   7   4
109  1    ECA    TEXT    6   6   6   3
```

I want to do a multiple regression with E1-E3 as my IVs and the mean score of M as my DV.

This is how I loaded my data.

```
myRegressionData = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Folder 1/Python/Regression data file.csv')
```

These are my x and y:

```
X_sk = myRegressionData[[col for col in myRegressionData.columns if col[:8] == 'E']]

Y = myRegressionData[['M{}'.format(ii) for ii in range(1, 19)]]
y = np.mean(Y, axis=1)
```

and this the code where I get the error:

```
myRegressionData.plot(kind='scatter',x = X_sk, y=np.mean(Y, axis=1))
```

returns

**ValueError**: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only

```
myRegressionData.info()
```

returns

RangeIndex: 90 entries, 0 to 89 Columns: 146 entries, IDOpenEndedResponse to EngagingAA dtypes: float64(10), int64(134), object(2) memory usage: 102.7+ KB

Comment: Without your data, we can't fully resolve this issue, for instance what does `myRegressionData.info()` show? Does it bork if you just did `myRegressionData.plot.scatter(x = X_sk, y = np.mean(Y, axis=1))` or just `myRegressionData.plot().bar()`

Comment: @EdChum that would be: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 90 entries, 0 to 89
Columns: 146 entries, IDOpenEndedResponse to EngagingAA
dtypes: float64(10), int64(134), object(2)
memory usage: 102.7+ KB                                      . No it doesn't work, I get the same error.

Comment: Please edit this into your question, besides the value error maybe bogus as a scatter plot can handle more than boolean values so you need to post a minimal example that includes raw data, your code to load the df, all code that reproduces the error and the desired output

Comment: Still need raw data unfortunately, you could have dodgy data

Comment: In your example data you only have one `M` target column but aggregate over across 18 target columns. Maybe you should indicate this by adding another `M` column in your sample data so that you have, say, `M1` and `M2`. Also you should probably update your code to use `col[:1] == 'E'` and `range(1, 3)`, or similar. Also remember that `range` is inclusive at the start, but not at the end.

Answer (score 1):

In the following:

```
myRegressionData.plot(kind='scatter',x = X_sk, y=np.mean(Y, axis=1))
```

`x` and `y` [expect column names](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), or indecies. `X_sk` and `np.mean(Y, axis=1)` is data. Supply the column names or use your plotter directly.

---

Example where we use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myRegressionData = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a0': 4, 'a1': 3, 'b0': 2, 'b1': 1}, 
    {'a0': 3, 'a1': 1, 'b0': 4, 'b1': 1}, 
    {'a0': 1, 'a1': 2, 'b0': 3, 'b1': 1}
])

X_sk = myRegressionData[[col for col in myRegressionData.columns if col[:1] == 'b']]
Y = myRegressionData[['a{}'.format(ii) for ii in range(0,2)]]
plt.scatter(X_sk['b0'], np.mean(Y, axis=1))
```

The example should be a simplified version of what you're doing.

---

If you insist on using the pandas DataFrame plotter you can do something like this:

```
y = pd.DataFrame(np.mean(Y, axis=1), columns=['y'])
df = pd.concat([X_sk, y], axis=1)
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='b0', y='y')
```

---

Having many X values, but only one y value and differentiate using colors:

```
X_sk = myRegressionData[[col for col in myRegressionData.columns if col[:1] == 'b']]
Y = myRegressionData[['a{}'.format(ii) for ii in range(0,2)]]
y = pd.DataFrame(np.mean(Y, axis=1))
yy = pd.concat([y, y])
plt.scatter(X_sk, yy, c=['b', 'r'])
```

---

Final alternative using `scatter_matrix`:

```
y = pd.DataFrame(np.mean(Y, axis=1), columns=['y'])
df = pd.concat([X_sk, y], axis=1)
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6, 6))
```

Comment: So that works but only with one column of X_SK at a time otherwise I get the error x and y must have the same size.

Comment: `model = sm.OLS(y, X_sk)`
`results = model.fit()`

#Create a plot 

`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
`fig = sm.graphics.plot_fit(results, 0, ax=ax)`
`plt.show()`    Would that work?

Comment: Se my update. Just add `y` several times. Other than that I recommend having a look at this question about scatterplot matrices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941207/is-there-a-function-to-make-scatterplot-matrices-in-matplotlib