# Pandas scatter_matrix plotting - additional arguments

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I am running Python 3.6 with Pandas version 0.19.2. On the code example below, I have two questions regarding the Pandas plotting function `scatter_matrix()`:

**1.**How can I colour-label the observations in the scatter plots with respect to the `Label` column?

**2.**How can I specify the number of bins for the histograms on the diagonal? Can I do this individually or just one bin number for all?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N= 1000
df_feat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
df_label = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], N), columns=['Label'])
df = pd.concat([df_feat, df_label], axis=1)
axes = pd.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
```

This is linked to [this more general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682144/matplotlib-analog-of-rs-pairs) one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your first question, there may be a less 'kludgey' way, but

`scatter_matrix(df,c=['r' if i == 1 else 'b' for i in df['Label']])`

To answer the second:

The scatter matrix can use the [pd.hist()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) api to use hist keywords passed in a dictionary

`scatter_matrix(df,hist_kwds={'bins':5})`

Comment: Thank you, I will try these out when I'm next to a computer.

Comment: [Here is a related post](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4834).